# How to setup Spring Logs for Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, log4j

Working on Spring MVC and not having Spring logs has made it hard to debug. I have read few other articles on this problem and none seem to help me.
`log4j.properties` is in `src` folder. `slf4j-api-1.5.11`, `slf4j-log4j12-1.5.11`, `slf4j-simple-1.5.11`, `commons-logging-1.1.jar` and `log4j-1.2.16.jar` jars are in the classpath.
Log4j content is:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console


# Console appender
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%-15.15t] %-5p %-30.30c{1} - %m%n
log4j.throwableRenderer=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedThrowableRenderer
```

But I don't see any Spring logs in my console.

> Note: Using Spring 3.1

Comment: http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-log-in-spring-with-slf4j-and-logback/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove `commons-logging-1.1.jar` and add `jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.11.jar`, as you need all logging calls to go through slf4j and then handled by log4j.

Also, you will need to add loggers for spring in log4j.properties, as indicated below. log4j.properties needs to end up in `tomcat/webapps/<application>/WEB-INF/classes`.

```
#Spring Framework
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework.oxm=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=WARN
```

Maven dependencies need to contain entries similar to following (taken from [Using SLF4J](http://blog.springsource.org/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/) section).
Note the exclusion of `commons-logging` and inclusion of `jcl-over-slf4j`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
       <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.14</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am not using MAVEN in my project. But removed `commons-logging` from  classpath and added `jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.8.jar`

Comment: It finally worked for me. There was SLF4j jar conflict. I am gonna check error regarding Spring MVC right away.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav added an answer to initial question. Check that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add this...

```
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
```

Also change `console` to `stdout`. See example

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out 
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Sorry, It didn't help!

Answer (score -1):

When I put log4j.properties to "src" folder I have no spring logs and message:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

When I moved back to src/main/resources - all works fine. Seems like log4j.properties must be placed at "classes" folder after deploy.

Comment: When using maven, by default, files in `src/main/resources` are copied to `target/classes` and end up correctly in the resulting .jar/.war. Unless explicitly instructed, maven will not copy files in `src`, which is against the standard use.